# Passing Javascript Parameters and Assigning to Variables

Tags: javascript, html

i want to pass one function generated value to another function.

example :

```
function mainFunc(){
var x = 1;
}

function doMatch(){
var tot = x + 1;
}
```

only if `doMath()` Function calls it will calculate total. it shouldn't call `mainFunc()` Again.

not like this

```
  function mainFunc(){
    var x = 1;
      return x;
    }

    function doMatch(){
    var tot = mainFunc() + 1;
    }
```

How can i do this. i think if we can make it global variable after it generated from the `mainFunc()` then every other function can access it.

we cant edit global variable value from function right?

Comment: if down voter can give me reason for the down vote with answer that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable outside the scope of both of these methods that is accessible from each.

```
function mainFunc(){
  window.x = 1;
}

function doMatch(){
  var tot = x + 1;
}
```

Comment: it didnt work. you saying. after it x assign 1 in mainFunc. global variable also will change to 1?

Comment: Yes global variable will be 1, that is what I assumed you wanted? What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: in doMath Function x is Undefined. i tried adding alert(x) to both function. mainFunc() gave me 1 but doMath gave me `undefined`

Comment: What are you expecting DoMatch() to return? It will be undefined as it doesn't know what to do. Tell it to `return tot;` and it will return 2.